# Opening and Balance amount query for different account in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to set opening and Balance column in postgresql query where i input specific date range and first opening data should be upto starting date and Balance should be (opening data + Debit - Credit) in each date wise row.

*** Here is my sample database name "opening_and_closing"

| date1 | acc_no | debit | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2017 | a | 500 | 0 |
| 02/01/2017 | a | 0 | 400 |
| 03/01/2017 | a | 100 | 0 |
| 04/01/2017 | a | 800 | 0 |
| 05/01/2017 | a | 0 | 700 |
| 06/01/2017 | a | 800 | 0 |
| 01/01/2017 | b | 500 | 0 |
| 02/01/2017 | b | 0 | 400 |
| 03/01/2017 | b | 100 | 0 |
| 04/01/2017 | b | 800 | 0 |
| 05/01/2017 | b | 0 | 700 |
| 06/01/2017 | b | 800 | 0 |

*** My expected query in postgresql
*** date range is 03/01/2017 to 06/01/2017

| date1 | acc_no | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | opening | 100 |
| 03/01/2017 | a | 100 | 0 | 200 |
| 04/01/2017 | a | 800 | 0 | 1000 |
| 05/01/2017 | a | 0 | 700 | 300 |
| 06/01/2017 | a | 800 | 0 | 1100 |

| date1 | acc_no | debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | opening | 100 |
| 03/01/2017 | b | 100 | 0 | 200 |
| 04/01/2017 | b | 800 | 0 | 1000 |
| 05/01/2017 | b | 0 | 700 | 300 |
| 06/01/2017 | b | 800 | 0 | 1100 |

Comment: How much are you offering to pay for someone to write this query for you?

Comment: and there is an up vote

Comment: Hi i see your profile.. And you never accepted answer and rarely put up your query into your question.. Please.. Do a favor for them like accepted the answer.. And we are here not do free service code for you..

Comment: #Caius Jard #guradil #dwir182, sorry dear i am a learner and unable to pay...

Comment: The Debit and Credit columns seem to be reversed in your example input.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Show us what you've tried, and what's not working. Also, when people spend time answering your questions, it's good if you accept their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Create a table name "opening_and_closing" in your database

```
create table opening_and_closing (date1 date, acc_no varchar(250), debit numeric,credit numeric);
```

***Insert Values in your "opening_and_closing" table

```
insert  into opening_and_closing
values  ('2017-01-01','a',500,0),
('2017-01-02','a',0,400),
('2017-01-03','a',100,0),
('2017-01-04','a',800,0),
('2017-01-05','a',0,700),
('2017-01-06','a',800,0),
('2017-01-01','b',500,0),
('2017-01-02','b',0,400),
('2017-01-03','b',100,0),
('2017-01-04','b',800,0),
('2017-01-05','b',0,700),
('2017-01-06','b',800,0);
```

***Now Execute the following query

```
select  date1,acc_no,opening,debit,credit,
        (opening+sum(debit-credit) OVER (partition by acc_no order by date1)) as balance
from

    (select date1,acc_no,debit,credit,
    (select sum(debit)-sum(credit) from opening_and_closing where date1 < '2017-01-03'   and  acc_no ='a') as opening

    from opening_and_closing
    where   date1 between '2017-01-03' and '2017-01-06'
    and acc_no ='a'
    group by 1,2,3,4
    order by date1)x
```